# How to make Emacs start using the Xetex engine as default

Tags: init-file, auctex

I am using Emacs to edit all the stuff I'm writing. As I make extensive use of fontspec, I would like to configure my Emacs (running within OpenSuse Linux)so as to start using the `xetex-engine` without going again and again through the pull-down menu `command -> TeXing options -> use xetex-engine`.

Answer (score 6):

From [AUCTeX's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dengine):

> User Option: **TeX-engine**
>
> This variable allows you to choose which TeX engine should be used for
>   typesetting the document, i.e. the executables which will be used when
>   you invoke the ‘TeX’ or ‘LaTeX’ commands. The value should be one of
>   the symbols defined in `TeX-engine-alist-builtin` or `TeX-engine-alist`.
>   The symbols ‘default’, ‘xetex’, ‘luatex’ and ‘omega’ are available
>   from the built-in list.

You can customize this variable or put something like this in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq TeX-engine 'xetex)
```

Answer (score 3):

[ I understand that your question relates to the use of AUCTeX (even though you did not say so explicitly), but here's the answer for the built-in LaTeX mode.  ]

The default command used when you do `C-c C-c` in the builtin LaTeX mode is taken to be the last one you used in the past (relying on the command's history).  So if you use `savehist-mode` (or some other such package) to remember your minibuffer histories across sessions, you don't have anything special to do:  just once use `xelatex ...` and it should then be used by default for subsequent latexing operations.

Note that this only works for the commands that `tex-compile` knows, and it only learned about `xelatex` (and `lualatex`) in Emacs-26, IIRC, so if you Emacs is older, you'll need to add something like

```
(with-eval-after-load `tex-mode
  (add-to-list 'tex-compile-commands
               '("xelatex %f" t "%r.pdf")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how to invoke a command in other ways than accessing it through a menu. If so:

`C-h k`, then use the menus to get where you want. Note the name of the command shown for that menu item in `*Help*`.

If a keyboard key sequence is also shown in `*Help*` then use that. If not, use `M-x` followed by the command name.

Take the Emacs tutorial: `C-h t` to learn more about using Emacs (invoking commands etc.).